# Come back from the moon, bringing back the samples

Tags: word-usage

Does using two **'back's** in a row sound awkward to you in this sentence?

> We have come **back** from the moon, bringing **back** the samples.

If so, how should I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to avoid using the same word twice, especially when there isn't much of a gap between uses in the sentence/paragraph.  It can distract from the intent.

For this sentence, try this alternative:

> We have *returned* from the moon, bringing back the samples.

Or:

> We have come back from the moon *with* the samples.

Other substitutions are possible, including removing "back" altogether:

> We have returned from the moon, bringing with us the samples.

Answer (score 1):

> We have returned from the moon, bringing back the samples.

or even more simply

> We have returned/come back from the moon with the samples.

Note that ***return*** is more formal than ***come back***.